# LaTeX database or lookup table

Tags: latex, lookup, lookup-tables

I'm writing im LaTeX about some experiments I recently conducted. The values of the experiments will be visible inside a table and described within the text. I want to separate the data from the presentation here, so I can insert the data in one single place and refer to it in the text - much like a database.

My first approach to this issue would be something like

```
\newcommand{\result1}{8.99}
\newcommand{\result2}{12.93}
...
```

So, I could just use `\result1` as a placeholder whereever needed.

However, I don't really like this solution. Can I solve it a bit more convenient using some kind of lookup table or database inside LaTeX? Maybe something like

```
\results{1}{2}  % 1 = experiment ID, 2 = dataset ID
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
\usepackage{xstring}
\newcommand{\mylookup}[1]{
    \IfEqCase{#1}{
        {1}{8.99}
        {2}{12.93}
    }
}
```

Comment: Please consider adding some text explaining your answer.